# LinearLayout changed into RelativeLayout itself after findViewByID ? Believe it or not

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

In my `incident_detail_fragment.xml`, there is a `LinearLayout` inside the ScrollView. It's `id` is `detail_line_layout`. But when I called it from java with `findViewById` method, it's no longer a `LinearLayout`, it became `RelativeLayout`. Could somebody explain about it?

here `incident_detail_fragment.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/headerLayout_incident_detial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
     >
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/headerLayout_incident_detial"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_incident_detail"
     >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_line_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout 
   android:id="@id/footer_incident_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

It became `RelativeLayout` like this.
[image]

Another strange thing is when I watched the `ScrollView`'s child at debugging mode. It's still `LinearLayout`.

[image]

The most awkward thing is that I compared the two IDs of **ScrollView's child** and **findViewByID's RelativeLayout**. They are not the same. 
ScrollView's child ID -> **2131230886**
RelativeLayout ID -> **2131230885**

Comment: is this id `detail_line_layout ` declared in any other layout file ?

Comment: Nope. But even I did so, findViewById will work only in view range. (view.findViewByID()).

Comment: @CristyYG once can you give the id from the resource name .. `int resId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("detail_line_layout", "id", getActivity().getPackageName());`  resId is same which you got from findviewbyid ?

Comment: The problem is solved. I didn't do anything else. Just clean/build and run gain. It didn't become RelativeLayout no more. :)